# Generate Random Same Colors in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, material-ui

I have successfully generated random colors. The problem is I also wanted to assign same random colors for the background color of the same `orderNumber`. How do I do this?

Please check my codesandbox
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictable-material-demo-forked-vb1txq?file=/demo.js)

```
const newColorFind = () => {
  for (let x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
    let value = arrayOfColorFunctions[index];

    randomColorString += value;
  }
  console.log(randomColorString);
};
```

Comment: Why close this question? Its not all about random numbers. I need to check if the same order number .

Comment: Can you update the question to be more specific regarding an issue? What isn't working with generating random colors?

Comment: @DrewReese. It is still to generate a random color BUT I also added there that if they have the same `orderNumber` then several rows of that would still have same backgroundColor

Comment: I understand your question now is really about more than just generating a color, but your question needs more context regarding the assignment/consumption of them. Can you include that part of your code in your question as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your sandbox isn't tracking:

1. Previously generated colors
2. Order numbers that have been assigned a color.

You can use a map object to track both, which allows for `O(1)` constant time lookup of either.

Example:

```
const colorMap = {};
const selectedColors = {};

const generateColor = () => {
  let randomColorString = "#";
  const arrayOfColorFunctions = "0123456789abcdef";
  for (let x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
    let value = arrayOfColorFunctions[index];

    randomColorString += value;
  }
  return randomColorString;
};

const newColorFind = id => {
  // If already generated and assigned, return
  if (colorMap[id]) return colorMap[id];

  // Generate new random color
  let newColor;

  do {
    newColor = generateColor();
  } while(selectedColors[newColor]);

  // Found a new random, unassigned color
  colorMap[id] = newColor;
  selectedColors[newColor] = true;

  // Return next new color
  return newColor;
}
```

Pass the currently iterated `orderNumber` to the color utility

```
<TableCell
  component="th"
  scope="row"
  sx={{ backgroundColor: newColorFind(row.orderNumber) }}
>
  {row.orderNumber}
</TableCell>
```

[image: Edit generate-random-same-colors-in-react]

[image]

Using PolishedJS `readableColor` utility to select the readable text color to use.
[image]

Comment: @Joseph Yes, that is possible, you'd just need to use a utility to compute the contrast ratio between black/white text and the random color. [readableColor](https://polished.js.org/docs/#readablecolor) from PolishedJS is a good candidate.

Comment: @Joseph I'm sure it's just a simple math formula to compute the contrast ratio between two colors.

Comment: @Joseph For the computation, you can always look at source code [here](https://github.com/styled-components/polished/blob/main/src/color/readableColor.js#L43-L56) for `readableColor` and [here](https://github.com/styled-components/polished/blob/main/src/color/getLuminance.js#L30-L38) for computing the luminance. Can you clarify that last question regarding assigning color for duplicate only? Like, you only want to highlight the orders with multiple order ids?

Comment: @Joseph Do a pass over the data first and compute which orders are duplicates and set an additional property, then on the second pass use the "isDuplicate" property that was added to grab a color.

Comment: @Joseph See the codesandbox for only highlighting duplicates.

Comment: @Joseph Yeah, on each cell, or call `getRowColor(row)` once to get the computed `color` and `backgroundColor` and pass what is relevant to each row/cell. For example, the row needs the background color, but the cells need the color. https://codesandbox.io/s/generate-random-same-colors-in-react-forked-yz5yc3