# Generate Same Random Color with Page refresh in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, web-deployment

In my application, I assign the same random color for the background color of the same `uniqueID` and I also want this color to be the same random color if the page reloads.

My approach and current behavior is similar to the solution in this prior post: [Generate Random Same Colors in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229785/generate-random-same-colors-in-react) however, the **colors change if the page is reloaded**.

**Question:** Is there a way to map the `uniqueID` to a random color, and have it persist different instances of my app using REACT?

See below my current code:

```
function getRandomColor(): string{
  return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
let colorMap = new Map<number, string>();
function setColor(uniqueId: number): string{
  if(colorMap.get(uniqueId) == null){
    colorMap.set(uniqueId,getRandomColor());
  }
  return colorMapping.get(id) + "";
}
//later in the code
color: setColor(Number(d_id)),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of the various storage options to store this and then restore on each page load:

- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)
- [Session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
- [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: so instead of using a map, i could use `sessionStorage,setItem(`id', getRandomColor())` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right and it can be retrieved with `getItem`. Also, if you needed the data to persist after the browser closes then use `LocalStorage` since sessions get cleared when the session ends (such as browser or tab is closed).